# Show that for any function $f_0 \in L^p(E)$ there is a function $g_0$ in $C \subset L^p(E)$ closed convex

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a measurable set $1< p<\infty$ and $C$ a closed bounded convex subset of $L^p(E)$. Show that for any function $f_0 \in L^p(E)$ there is a function $g_0$ in $C$ for which $$||g_0-f_0||_p \leq ||g-f_0||_p \text{ for all } g \text{ in } C$$

Attempt:

Not sure how to start.
We know:

$C$ closed: provided whenever ${f_n}$ is a sequence in $L^p(E)$ that converges strongly in $L^p(E)$ to f, then if each $f_n$ belongs to $C$, the limit $f$ also belongs to $C$.

$C$ convex: provided whenever $f$ and $g$ belong to $C$ and $\lambda \in [0, 1]$, then $\lambda f + (1- \lambda)g$ also belongs to $C$.

Any clues how i look at this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Define a sequence of sets $E_n =\{ x\in C: ||x-f_0||_p \leq \inf_{u\in C} ||u-f_0||_p +\frac{1}{n}\} .$ The set $E_n\subset E_{n-1} $ are closed bounded and convex hence weakly compact since $L_p$ is reflexive Banach space. Thus $$E=\bigcap_n E_n \neq \emptyset $$ so you can take as $g_0 $ any element of $E.$

Comment: elements of $L_p $ are functions.

Comment: Since $E_n$ are weakly compact, this means every sequence ${f_n}$ in $E_n$ has a subsequence that converges weakly to $f \in E_n$. Are you suggesting to take $g_0$ the limit of such a sequence?